# SelectedIndexChanged event of Picker control is failing

Tags: maui, picker

Using VS 2022, 17.6, I'm using a Picker control on a form and I created an event for `SelectedIndexChanged`. When I select a new item, the event fires correctly. However, the following code does not work and I'm not sure why.
As soon as the first line is hit (`Picker pck = sender as Picker;`), the method exits, no error, just exits.  I've put a breakpoint on the first line and I can look at sender in the debugger, it is a Picker control. I also tried typecasting, `(Picker)sender`, same thing.

Any thoughts?

```cs
private void nameSelect_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        Picker pck = sender as Picker;
        if (pck != null)
        {

        }
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        string s1 = ex.Message;
    }
}
```

Comment: Is this the entire method or do you have code inside the if-clause? Do you receive any messages in the Output window of Visual Studio? Does the method just exit or does the application actually crash? Does this occur in Debug or Release mode? If that's your actual code and you have optimizations enabled (disabled by default in Debug mode in MAUI apps), then the JIT compiler might optimize most of the method away, because it doesn't actually do anything.

Comment: No, this is the entire code.  I just put the if (pck != null) so I could place a break point after the line above it.  No exception is thrown, never hit the catch block.  I'm not seeing any info in the output window.  I also defined an unhandled exception handler in App.xaml.cs, with a breakpoint but it is not thrown either.

Comment: Put a line of code inside the if-block and try again. Are you using Debug mode? FYI, you can also put a breakpoint on the closing brace of a code block to observe the code above it, you don't need extra code for a breakpoint. I would also recommend using pattern matching using the [is operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/is) instead of casting, e.g.: `if(sender is not Picker pck) return;`.

Comment: Remove breakpoint. Use debug.writeline to write to VS Output Pane. After Picker pck line, and in exception. This is a different way to see if it reaches either place. If not, something may be corrupted. delete solution’s hidden .vs folder, as well as .obj and .bin folders.

Comment: Thank you for all the responses.  Turned off JIT and all appears to be working normally again.  As suggested, it looks like this was more of an optimization issue

Comment: AFAIK, the JIT cannot be turned off or disabled entirely, because it is required to compile the IL code to machine code during runtime (hence just-in-time, JIT). Only optimizations can be disabled. This should only be possible with native AOT (ahead-of-time) compilation.